# Select and display a random group box each time a button is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, random, groupbox

I am making a quiz game and one of my levels is going to be fill in the blanks. In this level I have laid out 10 different group boxes with a label and text boxes in each of them. I would like to be able to randomly select a different group box each time the next button is clicked. The next button will appear after the check button has been clicked to check the users answers in the text boxes and change the score variable. I need to ensure that the same group box doesn't show up twice.

```
private void frmLevel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBoxList.Clear();
        btnNext.Hide();
        this.BackgroundImage = gameClass.background;

        groupBoxList.Add(groupBox1);
        groupBoxList.Add(groupBox2);
        groupBoxList.Add(groupBox3);
        groupBoxList.Add(groupBox4);
        groupBoxList.Add(groupBox5);
        groupBoxList.Add(groupBox6);
        groupBoxList.Add(groupBox7);
        groupBoxList.Add(groupBox8);
        groupBoxList.Add(groupBox9);
        groupBoxList.Add(groupBox10);

        foreach (GroupBox box in groupBoxList) 
        {
            box.Hide();

        }

        Random groupBoxChooser = new Random(); }
```

Comment: is this a web or desktop?. please show the code you already working on and where you get stuck.

Comment: @FedriQrueger This is a windows form application. Should&#39;ve said that, sorry. I&#39;ve put all of my group boxes in a list but I&#39;m not sure how to randomly select them. To put them in a list I have just done groupBoxList.Add(groupBox1)          and up to groupBox10.

Comment: @FedriQrueger I have also hidden all group boxes on form load by using; foreach(GroupBox box in groupBoxList){ box.Hide(); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`Random.Next()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) to draw the lucky number:

```
var luckyNumber = groupBoxChooser.Next(0,groupboxList.Count);
```

If you want that to work from other methods as well, you should make the random number chooser a field instead of a local variable, so move this line out of the Form Load event into the class:

```
Random groupBoxChooser = new Random();
```

Then, you need the [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc(v=vs.110).aspx) to access an item of the list

```
groupboxList[luckyNumber].Show();
```

Since it does still not work for you, here's my full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GroupBoxRnd
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        IList<GroupBox> groupboxList = new List<GroupBox>();
        Random groupBoxChooser = new Random();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Find all group boxes
            foreach (Control control in Controls)
            {
                if (control.GetType() == typeof(GroupBox))
                    groupboxList.Add((GroupBox)control);
            }

            // Hide all of them
            foreach (GroupBox box in groupboxList)
            {
                box.Hide();
            }

            // Show a random one
            var luckyNumber = groupBoxChooser.Next(0, groupboxList.Count);
            groupboxList[luckyNumber].Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. I have put this:                             var number = groupBoxChooser.Next(0, groupBoxList.Count);
           groupBoxList[number].Show();     in my form load. I have also declared my random (Random groupBoxChooser = new Random();)   outside of the form load.     When I go to run it, nothing shows up.

Comment: Just realised that sometimes it shows a group boxes, other times it does not.

Comment: @RyanS: I have added my full code. Works fine. I have no issues. There must be something else in your code that I'm not aware of - or maybe a big group box contains other group boxes.

Comment: I think that's what happened. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RyanS: once your issue is solved, consider checking the checkmark besides my answer so that others know the problem is solved and no more answers are needed.